# JsonConverter not working in integration tests

Tags: .net, integration-testing, jsonconvert

I've enabled my API to serialize/deserialize enum using string values. To do that I've added JsonStringEnumConverter to the list of supported JsonConverters in my API's Startup class:

```
.AddJsonOptions(opts =>
{
    var enumConverter = new JsonStringEnumConverter();
    opts.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(enumConverter);
});
```

It works fine- my API succeessfully serialize and deserialize enums as a string.

Now- I'm trying to build integration test for my API and having some issue.
I'm using `HttpContentJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsync` to deserialize the API response but an exception is thrown over an enum property.

The problem is obvious- `HttpContentJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsync` is not aware to the list of converters used by the API (since, as I mentioned earlier, I've added the `JsonStringEnumConverter` to the list of supported converters and it works fine).

If I do this in my test function:

```
var options = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
SomeClass result= await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<SomeClass>(options);
```

Then the enum property is deserialized and no exception is thrown. However now, `ReadFromJsonAsync`  is only aware of `JsonStringEnumConverter` and not to other JSON converters that are used by the API (like Guid converter)

How can I make sure that `HttpContentJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsync` will be able to use all JSON converters that are used by the API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, unfortunately, no way to achieve this out of the box. The reason is that the "designers" of the System.Text.Json APIs decided, in an unbelievably baffling move, to make said APIs static - probably to mimic the well-know Newtonsoft.Json - but static APIs, of course, cannot carry state along with them. For more context I [refer you to the feature request to fix this poor design](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31094).

I actually came up with [a solution](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31094#issuecomment-674990782) in that FR, which I've tweaked a little since I concocted it:

```
public interface IJsonSerializer
{
    JsonSerializerOptions Options { get; }

    Task<T> DeserializeAsync<T>(Stream utf8Json, CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    // other methods elided for brevity
}

public class DefaultJsonSerializer : IJsonSerializer
{
    private JsonSerializerOptions _options;
    public JsonSerializerOptions Options
        => new JsonSerializerOptions(_options); // copy constructor so that callers cannot mutate the options

    public DefaultJsonSerializer(IOptions<JsonSerializerOptions> options)
        => _options = options.Value;

    public async Task<T> DeserializeAsync<T>(Stream utf8Json, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(utf8Json, Options, cancellationToken);

    // other methods elided for brevity
}
```

Essentially you define a wrapper interface with method signatures identical to the static ones of `JsonSerializer` (minus the `JsonSerializerOptions` parameter as you want to use the ones defined on the class), then a default implementation of said interface that delegates to the static `JsonSerializer` methods. Map the interface to the implementation in `Startup.ConfigureServices` and instead of calling the static `JsonSerializer` methods in the classes that need to handle JSON, you inject your JSON interface into those classes and use it.

Given that you're using `HttpContentJsonExtensions`, you will additionally need to define your own wrapper version of that extension class that duplicates its method signatures but replaces their `JsonSerializerOptions` parameters with instances of your JSON serialization interface, then passes said interface's options through to the underlying `HttpContentJsonExtensions` implementation:

```
public static class IJsonSerializerHttpContentJsonExtensions
{
    public static Task<object?> ReadFromJsonAsync(this HttpContent content, Type type, IJsonSerializer serializer, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        => HttpContentJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsync(content, type, serializer.Options, cancellationToken);

    // other methods elided for brevity
}
```

Is it painful? Yes. Is it unnecessary? Also yes. Is it stupid? A third time, yes. But such is Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Rventually I used JSON.Net for that one...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact issue as described by the OP and my code looked very much the same except I had and Enum and DateOnly converter. I was using the System.Text.Json classes. For me, the problem was that I needed to change another property on the serialization options. I previously just had this:

```
// Setup custom serializers
var serializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
   Converters = { new Data.DateOnlyConverter(), new Data.EnumStatusConverter() }
};
```

I needed to add the following to the serializerOptions object:

```
serializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
```

and then my tests could deserialize the values from my PostAsAsync functions.

Answer (score 0):

Another options is to utilize the options configured in the application.
In my fixture (WebApplicationFactory) constructor I query for the `IOptions<JsonOotions>` and store it.

Then either create `GetFromJsonAsync` in fixture that creates client and calls endpoint with options or pass them to HttpClient.

Hope it helps